# sum a column in a collection of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a collection of array-like objects like this :

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
```

And I would like to `sum the columns` (if u think of this as a 4x2 array) such that:

```
col1_sum = 16
col2_sum = 20
```

What is the best way of doing this is JS?

I tried using `underscore's _.reduce` function like so:

```
var col1_sum =_.reduce(a, function(memo,obj){ return memo + parseFloat(obj[0]);},0)
```

but I get an "undefined" error

any ideas? thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could always kick it old school.  It's not pretty, but it works.

```
col1_sum = 0;
col2_sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    col1_sum += a[i][0];
    col2_sum += a[i][1];
}
```

My other thought was to use jQuery's `each` function, but I guess you're not looking for a jQuery solution?

EDIT - Who needs `jQuery.each`?  Just use JavaScript's `Array.forEach`:

```
var col1_sum = 0;
var col2_sum = 0;

a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]];
a.forEach(function(element, index, array) { col1_sum += element[0]; col2_sum += element[1]; });

alert(col1_sum);
alert(col2_sum);
```

Comment: `Who needs jQuery.each?` Probably people that have jQuery and don't want to shim Array.forEach support for IE<=8.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I know, I know.  I was being flippant.  I use jQuery.each so much that I had forgotten about Array.forEach.

Comment: Heheh true, though I use jQuery's each/map/grep a lot, the ES5 array methods are very nice and useful when developing new applications.

Answer (score 3):

I made a simple jsfiddle from your underscore reduce code, and it seems to be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/PdL5P/

```
var a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]

var col1_sum = _.reduce(a, function(memo,obj){ return memo + parseFloat(obj[0]); }, 0 );

$("#sum").html(col1_sum)
```

Are you sure that "a" is defined at that point of your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can also kick it new school:

```
var sumColumnJS = function sumColumnJS(array, col) {
    var sum = 0;
    array.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
        sum += value[col];
    });
    return sum;
};
```

or use the `_.each` array iterator:

```
sumColumn_ = function sumColumn_(array, col) {
    var sum = 0;
    _.each(a, function (item) {
        sum += item[col];
    });
    return sum;
};
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HTqvf/**

Answer (score 0):

Simple iteration, as in any traditional language

```
    var col1_sum = 0, col2_sum = 0, row;
    for (row in a)
    {
        col1_sum += a[row][0];
        cos2_sum += a[row][1];
    }
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `for...in` on an array, though.  See, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Answer (score -1):

I would do this.

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
col1_sum = _.sum(_.map(a,0))
col2_sum = _.sum(_.map(a,1))
```

Comment: user wants solution in underscore js. _.sum() is not underscore.js function.